# Append list within nested for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have defined some data, which appends to some lists. in order to do this, I need to put them into some sort of nested loop condition. First a range between 1-15 creates then rebarnumber calculates, within the loop, I set those conditions when `n <= rebarnumber` is matched, `*do something*`, then continue when `n >= rebarnumber` *`do something else`*. The problem is when above conditions fullfilled, I do except to get list with full length of range numbers.

***But instead gets this result.***

```
[49.0] 1
[49.0, 49.0] 2
[49.0, 49.0, 49.0] 3
[49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0] 4
[49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0] 5
[49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0] 6
[49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0] 7
[49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 84.0] 8
[49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 84.0, 49.0, 84.0] 9
[49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 84.0, 49.0, 84.0] 10
[49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 84.0, 49.0, 84.0] 11
[49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 84.0, 49.0, 84.0] 12
[49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 84.0, 49.0, 84.0] 13
[49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 84.0, 49.0, 84.0] 14
[49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 84.0, 49.0, 84.0] 15
```

***Desired result, (just shown last 2 lines of print)***

```
[49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 84.0, 84.0, 84.0, 84.0, 84.0, 84.0, 84.0] 14
[49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 84.0, 84.0, 84.0, 84.0, 84.0, 84.0, 84.0, 84.0] 15
```

**The code:**

```
h = 300
cb = 35
ct = 35
ca = 35
b= 300
y = 12
d = h - cb
ds = ct
a = 25
yb = 8
rebarnumber = math.floor((b-(2*cb+2*yb+y))/a)
disc = []
dis = []
Asi = []
Asci = []

for n in range(1,16):
    if n <= rebarnumber+1:
        Asi.append(int(3.1416/4*(y)**2))
        dis.append( h - (cb + yb + y/2 ))
        Asci.append(int(3.1416/4*(y)**2))
        disc.append( ct + yb + y/2 )
        if n >= rebarnumber:
            Asi.append(int(3.1416/4*(y)**2))
            dis.append( h - (cb + yb + y/2 ) - ca)
            Asci.append(int(3.1416/4*(y)**2))
            disc.append( cb + yb + y/2 + ca)
    print(disc, n)
```

What's it I do wrong?! any help!

Comment: That depends on what you want to have happen. You showed what you didn't want, but didn't clearly describe what you want. Could you show your desired output? Did you try debugging?

Comment: You speak of a nested loop, but there is only one loop.

Comment: See my updated image

Comment: Probably you must unindent the second `if` block one level (and maybe adjust the condition).

Comment: I would like to change condition, else statement wont use here. But I want to keep it simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of awkward things in your code. Let's clear those up first.

1. You have obviously imported `math` since you are using `math.floor`. Why not also use `math.pi` instead of 3.1416? And, since it's a constant, why not make use of the standard PEP8 naming convention, ALL_CAPS? Also, why not use :

   ```
   import math

   # ...

   PI_Y2_4 = int((math.pi * y ** 2) / 4)
   ```
2. There are several "common subexpressions" that you could store as variables. Since, in your example code, they appear to be constants, you might even make them constants. But even if they aren't constant in your real code, you can gain clarity, avoid errors, and improve speed by computing them just once:

   ```
   for n in range(1, 16):
       cbyby_2 = cb + yb + y / 2
       ctyby_2 = ct + yb + y / 2

       if n <= rebarnumber+1:
           Asi.append(PI_Y2_4)
           Asci.append(PI_Y2_4)
           dis.append(h - cbyby_2)
           disc.append(ctyby_2)

           if n >= rebarnumber:
               Asi.append(PI_Y2_4)
               Asci.append(PI_Y2_4)
               dis.append(h - cbyby_2 - ca)
               disc.append(cbyby_2 + ca)
   ```

   Also, are you sure about `ct` and `cb` when computing values for `disc`? Everything else stays the same, but those two change. Could that be a typo?

Now, with those issues out of the way, let's look at your "got" versus "wanted" examples. You "got" a bunch of lists that stop growing at `n == 9`. You "wanted" a bunch of lists that kept growing (by one) up to `n == 15`.

Looking at the shape of your code, I see this:

```
for ...:
    if ...
        if ...
    print()
```

That says the `print` statement will occur every time, but the `append` methods will only be invoked when the first `if` statement passes. Furthermore, since the second `if` statement is contained inside the first `if` statement, when that statement passes you will append *twice* to each list.

Obviously, that's not what you want. Instead, I suspect you're trying to do a sort of `if/else` series, where one set of behavior pertains up to 8 or 9, and then another set of behavior takes over.

Since you mentioned `else` in a comment, I'm guessing this is a homework assignment or something where you haven't learned `else` yet.

In that case, you need to make sure your conditions are directly reversed from each other! The easiest way to do that is using `not`. (Note the two `if` statements are indented the same amount! The second `if` is not contained inside the first.):

```
for n in ...:
    ...
    low_rebar = (n <= rebarnumber + 1)

    if low_rebar:
        Asi.append(PI_Y2_4)
        Asci.append(PI_Y2_4)
        dis.append(h - cbyby_2)
        disc.append(ctyby_2)

    if not low_rebar:
        Asi.append(PI_Y2_4)
        Asci.append(PI_Y2_4)
        dis.append(h - cbyby_2 - ca)
        disc.append(cbyby_2 + ca)

    print(disc, n)
```

If you haven't used boolean expressions, you might not be comfortable storing the result in a variable. In that case you can spell it out:

```
    if n <= rebarnumber + 1:
        ...
    if not (n <= rebarnumber + 1):
        ...
```

Or you could mathematically reverse the condition:

```
    if n > rebarnumber + 1:
```

Comment: Your explanation and solution is excellent and pedagogical. That solved my problem and much more.... Thanks a lot for helping.